# Error in installing MySQL-python==1.2.5

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install `MySQL-python==1.2.5` in my virtualenv on Mac using pip:

```
pip install MySQL-python==1.2.5
```

Getting the below error.

```
MySQL-python==1.2.5 Collecting MySQL-python==1.2.5 From cffi callback <function _verify_callback at 0x105e815f0>: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/harshit.jain/Documents/workspace/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 309, in wrapper
    _lib.X509_up_ref(x509) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'   Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)': /simple/mysql-python/ From cffi callback <function
_verify_callback at 0x107798758>: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/harshit.jain/Documents/workspace/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 309, in wrapper
    _lib.X509_up_ref(x509) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'   Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)': /simple/mysql-python/ From cffi callback <function
_verify_callback at 0x1077c9488>: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/harshit.jain/Documents/workspace/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 309, in wrapper
    _lib.X509_up_ref(x509) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'   Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)': /simple/mysql-python/ From cffi callback <function
_verify_callback at 0x1077c95f0>: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/harshit.jain/Documents/workspace/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 309, in wrapper
    _lib.X509_up_ref(x509) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'   Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)': /simple/mysql-python/ From cffi callback <function
_verify_callback at 0x1077c9500>: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/harshit.jain/Documents/workspace/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 309, in wrapper
    _lib.X509_up_ref(x509) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'   Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)': /simple/mysql-python/ From cffi callback <function
_verify_callback at 0x1077c9668>: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/harshit.jain/Documents/workspace/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 309, in wrapper
    _lib.X509_up_ref(x509) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'   Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/mysql-python/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/mysql-python/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)) - skipping
```

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQL-python==1.2.5 (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for MySQL-python==1.2.5

Comment: As a workaround I was able to install the package by setting the pypi.org as trusted host

`code`
pip install MySQL-python --trusted-host="pypi.org"

Answer (score -1):

see the last 2 lines:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQL-python==1.2.5 (from versions: ) 
No matching distribution found for MySQL-python==1.2.5
```

The version of MySQL-pytho lib problem. Maybe you could try another version of MySQL-python.

Comment: I tried to install without specifying a version number. Still getting the same error.